# Problem installing ubuntu with nvidia geforce gfx 850

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I have problems installing Ubuntu 14.04, Ubuntu 15.04

Sometimes I got installed Ubuntu (dont know why, after trying a lot of times) but the system crashes suddenly when I'm working

I got this error on the ubuntu installation

```
kernel: [    6.152654] nouveau E[   PFIFO][0000:01:00.0] SCHED_ERROR [UNK06 ]
```

I also try to install fedora, and redhat... but it seems that theres an incompatibility with my video card (Nvidia Geforce 850M)

After install Ubuntu with the default video card driver nouveau.I tried to install the nvidia-352 but it causes that my computer crashes, then when I reboot I got a blank screen...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally it is recommended to use the NVIDIA drivers from the Ubuntu repositories.
But as you are experiencing issues - you can install the latest official NVIDIA drivers.
These drivers already are in the Ubuntu 16.04 (to be released in April) repositories.
Please note that Ubuntu 15.04 is not supported anymore, so install Ubuntu 14.04.

Install Ubuntu and the drivers this way - boot from Ubuntu installation media.

Select Try Ubuntu without installing and press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line and press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

On the desktop start the installation process and after it has finished reboot.

Select Ubuntu in the GRUB boot menu and press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line and press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

On the login screen press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.
Enter your user name and the password - then execute these commands :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-361 nvidia-prime
sudo reboot
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested me... After that...
it shows me the splash screen.. and then a blank screen... (but the login sounds.

if I reboot, and put the nomodeset... I can see the login screen after splash, but when I login, the system shows me again the login screen...

I cant login even if I put nomodeset or nouveau.modeset=0

The last time this happend to me I tried follow this guide: "Screen Blanks/Monitor Turns Off" on http://goo.gl/ZMghyn But it didnt work for me because in my /etc/X11/xorg.conf has two blocks with the line "Section "Screen"", so I dont know where to change it

Comment: This is my /etc/X11/xorg.conf file https://www.dropbox.com/s/zyu2soq0v6ewjaz/xorg.conf?dl=0

Comment: @VictorHugoArangoA. : Please check whether there are settings in BIOS to activate the NVIDIA card or the switchable mode and do not connect an external monitor before or during the installation process. Another attempt is to uninstall all NVIDIA software (sudo apt-get purge nvidia*) and after the reboot ... reinstall the drivers in the way described. The  correct xorg.conf file should be generated automatically.

Comment: I purge the drivers and then reinstall the drivers without the screen... but the xorg is exactly the same that the file I sent you...
When I purge the the drivers and return to Ubuntu desktop with nomodeset, I recieved a notification..... that told me that the resolutions didnt worked... https://www.dropbox.com/s/i0kot4s5h98gx4j/20160326_062503.jpg?dl=0
I tried to change the resolution before to make a new driver's installation, but is not possible to change the resolution from 1920x1080 via the "Displays" in system configuration

Comment: @VictorHugoArangoA. : Why and where do you use nomodeset ? Did you add this to /etc/default/grub ? Please remove nomodeset ... then purge and reinstall the drivers exactly as described in the answer ! :)

Comment: No... I only used nomoset after I purged the nvidia driver... because it failed... (to login and work in ubuntu, just to test) I added in Grub in the boot options...

For the installation, I added nouveau.modeset=0 (but not nomodeset) .... and install nvidia... after that I reboot.. exactly how you told me... but it didnt worked..

Comment: This is my /etc/default/grub

https://www.dropbox.com/s/iquiz6g72l8e9ll/grub?dl=0

Comment: @VictorHugoArangoA. Try it this way : Purge the xorg.conf file and repeat everything ... otherwise I'm running out of ideas ... this should work ...  :)

Comment: I'm noob in ubuntu.. I dont want to crash the system... How can I purge the xorg.conf?

Comment: @VictorHugoArangoA. : On the login screen press Ctrl+Alt+F1 - enter user name and password - execute : sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf ... then execute : sudo apt-get purge nvidia* ... then execute : sudo reboot ... from now on follow the instructions given in the answer. :)

Comment: I repeat what you said exactly like you said... but still happened the same thing (Black screen and the sound that means I have to login)
I read in your article http://goo.gl/aZ1ozQ that my nvidia has "Optimus" that means that it could work with a GPU (intel) or a GPU (nvidia)
So.. I change it to intel "prime-select intel" and it worked!  but how can I make it work with the NVIDIA GPU? is there a problem if I work with the intel GPU? (maybe an overload, or something like that?)

Comment: @VictorHugoArangoA. : Of course you can work with intel graphics, it even has lower power consumption. You can use NVIDIA X Server Settings -> PRIME Profiles to switch to NVIDIA graphics. :)

Comment: but.. do you have any suggestion to make it work with the "prime-select nvidia".. why is  happening the problem?

Comment: @VictorHugoArangoA. : It must have something to do with the general hardware and the BIOS ... every hardware is different and vendor dependent ... and this solution worked and works in nearly all cases. :)

Comment: should I report my problem to nvidia? or someone else? I think its important that the vendor fix it for other users...

Comment: @VictorHugoArangoA. : You should report it to the PC manufacturer, because the NVIDIA drivers work fine on most of all machines. :)

Answer (score 0):

After so many tries... I discover in some forum that you can disable the nauveau drivers to install ubuntu...

I have to press the shift key.. when the system starts... that shows you the grub2 screen... select installation and then press e (for edit boot settings) then put the word  "nomodeset" before the "quiet splash".. Save and reboot... 
Continue the installation process

once again you install ubuntu, the nauveau error is going to appear again... if you want that to disappear without installing nvidia.. just repeat the procedure... but put the word "nomoset" on the boot of the normal start up...

I still dont have my nvidia video card configured.. because everytime I try to configure them... my system shows a blank screen after splash... (but still hear the login sound, so I think is video card problems only)

You can check this link for more info about installing the drivers...
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia